# what is wrong with the syntax of this cron configuration

Tags: configuration, cron

The cron configuration of bfd appears to be wrong

```
MAILTO=
SHELL=/bin/bash
*/3 * * * * root /usr/local/sbin/bfd -q
```

It is the original setting created by the installation.

The cron.log gives this error -  `Error: bad minute; while reading /etc/cron.d/bfd` but it looks perfectly fine to me.

Comment: What version of cron? What OS? Not all versions of cron out there accept the */3 syntax.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu Hardy 8.04.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove the first two lines

Answer (score 4):

Setting environment variables in your crontab files, as in  your example...

```
MAILTO=
SHELL=/bin/bash
```

...is only supported in certain versions of cron.  In particular, crond by Paul Vixie, which is typical on many Linux distributions, supports this syntax.  It looks like Hardy may be using something else.  Looking at the crontab(5) man page should give you more details on the syntax supported by your locally installed version of cron.

If you need to ensure that environment variables are set correctly, you can set them on the individual crontab command line, like this:

```
*/3 * * * * root env MAILTO= SHELL=/bin/bash /usr/local/sbin/bfd -q
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem - setting environment variables *is* supported by your version of cron, but instead of

```
 MAILTO=
```

use

```
 MAILTO=""
```